# npm install not working with jfrog artifactory saas account

Tags: npm, artifactory

We have setup an npm with jfrog artifactory saas. The npm has both npm-local and npm-remote repository.

The npm-remote repository points to https://registry.npmjs.org with default settings.

I have the ~/.npmrc as follows (following instructions from artifactory)

```
_auth="[auth]"
email=[email address]
always-auth=true
registry=https://[company-name].jfrog.io/centricsoftware/api/npm/npm/
```

I was even able to publish an npm module to the jfrog artifactory server.

The trouble I have with install npm modules via jfrog artifactory

```
$>npm install express
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized: express@^4.15.3

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/[user]/.npm/_logs/2017-06-28T12_14_24_852Z-debug.log
```

The contents of the log file are as follows

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'express' ]
2 info using npm@5.0.4
3 info using node@v8.1.2
4 verbose npm-session 91f67a25a5bc9570
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 401 https://centricsoftware.jfrog.io/centricsoftware/api/npm/npm/express 6360ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for express@^4.15.3 401 Unauthorized: express@^4.15.3
9 verbose stack Error: 401 Unauthorized: express@^4.15.3
9 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:41:19)
9 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
9 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
9 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
9 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:762:5)
9 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:733:5)
10 verbose cwd /Users/rohitghatol/tmp/try
11 verbose Darwin 16.6.0
12 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "express"
13 verbose node v8.1.2
14 verbose npm  v5.0.4
15 error code E401
16 error 401 Unauthorized: express@^4.15.3
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What am I going wrong here?

Cheers
Rohit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to this npm [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16528) which was introduced with the npm 5.0 release.
A fix for this issue will be deployed to Artifactory SaaS in the next couple of days.
In addition, the npm team is working on a fix on the client side as well.